# How can I force a footnote to appear on the same page as a particular displayed-math environment?

Tags: math-mode, footnotes

In this example, `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` are used respectively inside and immediately outside of an `align*` environment to create a footnote. (Here the equation-numbering system is being abused as a way to place explanatory notes to the right of the working. A footnote is desired here because the explanatory note in question is excessively long and is forced onto its own line, which looks ugly.) However, because I have contrived to put the `align*` environment at the bottom of the page, the footnote is getting shifted onto the following page. This is undesirable. It would be much better if the footnote were on the same page as the `align*` environment.

(Straightforward use of `\footnote` does not work in the `align*` environment. The standard solution, as described in answers to other TeX/LaTeX Stack Exchange questions, is to use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` as seen here. But just doing this does not address this issue.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, reqno]{amsart}

\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newcommand{\tie}{\bowtie}
\newcommand{\ordtie}{\mathord{\tie}}

\begin{document}

Here is some vertical space to force the align* environment to the
bottom of this page, so that the problem is exposed.\vspace*{15cm}

\begin{proposition}
   Behold: a proposition.
\end{proposition}

\begin{proof}
   We first check that $f$ satisfies both parts of Definitions (number).
   For (i), let $v \in V_{(G / \ordtie) / \ordtie''}$. Then
   $v = \big[[v']_{\tie}\big]_{\tie''}$ for some $v' \in V_G$, and we have
   \begin{align*}
      \pi_{G / \ordtie'}f(v) &= \pi_{G / \ordtie'}\big(f\b(){\b[]{[v']_{\tie}}_{\tie''}}\big)
                          \\ &= \pi_{G / \ordtie'}\big([v']_{\tie'}\big)
                                \tag{by Proposition (number)}
                          \\ &= \pi_G(v')
                              = \pi_{G / \ordtie}\big([v']_{\tie}\big)
                              = \pi_{(G / \ordtie) / \ordtie''}\big(\big[[v']_{\tie}\big]_{\tie''}\big)
                                \tag{\footnotemark}
                          \\ &= \pi_{(G / \ordtie) / \ordtie''}(v),
   \end{align*}
   \footnotetext{Here we are using (three times) the definition from
   Definitions (number) of the parity map of a quotient graph.}
   as required. For (ii), let $\{u, v\} \in U_{(G / \ordtie) / \ordtie''}$;
   then there exists $\{u', v'\} \in U_G$ such that
   $u = \big[[u]_{\tie}\big]_{\tie''}$ and $v = \big[[v]_{\tie}\big]_{\tie''}$. We have
   \[ \text{some more displayed mathematics, I daresay.}
      \]
   And that's all.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

How might I force the footnote to be on the same page as the `\align*` environment, given that the `\footnotetext` command cannot be placed inside the environment (for the same reason, I assume, that simply using `\footnote` does not work inside the environment)?

Comment: This is not recommended as it will be confusing for the readers. I'd rather recommend directly writing `In the second to last line we are using (three times) ...`

Comment: given the size of the footnote, using `\enlargethispage` probably isn't going to do it.  a non-recommended possibility is to allow breaks within the `align*` and explicitly encourage one just before the line that requires the footnote.